# Unable to round simple javascript calculation

Tags: javascript, rounding

Currently this code outputs a string in two decimal places and I need it to be rounded to the closest integer. I had a play around with "math.round" but was unable to get it to work. Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("blog-body").innerHTML;
  var n = str.match(/(\w+)/g).length;
  var x = n / 200;
  var y = x.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = y + ' Min |';
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round to at most 2 decimal places, if necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/how-to-round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-if-necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `toFixed(0)`

Rounding to nearest integer: `(123.123).toFixed(0)` results in `123`

`(123.89).toFixed(0)` results in `124`

---

You can also use `Math.round(123.3)` results in `123` and `Math.round(123.89)` results in `124`